# Better to allow an object type of 'id' or provide two arguments for two different types for a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Imagine that a method is going to add an object to either a certain NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary. Is it better (and why) to allow just a single argument with type `id`, or allow two--one for the array and one for the dictionary?

For example:

```
- (void)addObjectToArray:(NSMutableArray *)anArray
            orDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)aDictionary;
```

vs.

```
- (void)addObjectToArrayOrDictionary:(id);
```

If using the first option, I'd just pass `nil` as the parameter to whichever one I don't need (i.e. if adding to a dictionary, i'd pass `nil` as the array parameter).

Comment: Dictionary expects a key apart from the object to store, so how are you passing the key?

Comment: The key is constructed based on a couple different integer values that the object has as properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither — I'd implement two separate methods, one for the array and one for the dictionary:

```
- (void)addObjectToArray:(NSMutableArray *)anArray;
- (void)addObjectToDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)aDictionary;
```

It's much simpler, more testable and more maintainable than

1. A method with an awkward signature, and unclear behavior depending on its arguments (e.g. what happens when the arguments are both `nil` or both not `nil`?); or
2. A weakly-typed method that accepts any random Objective-C instance, and has to validate its type at runtime anyway.

Comment: Of course, both methods presumably do very similar things, so they should both call through to another method that contains their shared implementation (if possible.) No sense in writing the *code* twice.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock and @JonathanGrynspan. I should be able to spend a bit of time re-factoring my code tonight, afterwhich I imagine I'll accept this answer.